# Apache 2.4.12 Redirect Wordpress subfolder to another server ip address

Tags: .htaccess, reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, wordpress, mod-proxy

I am running wordpress inside the laravel **public** folder which acts as the root of my site. How do I redirect to another server ip address i.e. (xx.xx.xx.xxx) when one accesses the following subfolder: **example.com/forum**

The other server runs nginx with the forum as the only site.

Here is my apache vhost configuration for the site:

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAdmin me@example.com

   DocumentRoot /var/www/example

   RewriteEngine on
   ProxyRequests off

   #Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

   #Redirect forum subdirectory requests to forum server
   RewriteRule ^/forum$ https://example.com/forum/ [R] [L]   
   RewriteRule ^/forum/(.*) http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/$1 [P]

   <Directory /var/www/example>
     AllowOverride all  
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Application **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(live|api|auth|_debugbar)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(live|api|auth|_debugbar)/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ laravel.php [L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    #admin panel route
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?admin-panel/(.*) $1wp-admin/$2?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
    RewriteRule ^login(.*) wp-login\.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

    # uploaded ﬁles
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?ﬁles/(.+) wp-includes/ms-ﬁles.php?ﬁle=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to add:

```
Redirect permanent /forum http://otherserver
```

to your apache vhost config, or to add:

```
RewriteRule ^/forum(.*)$ http://otherserver/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

to your .htaccess.

Comment: I want to use the same certificate for both servers since my certificate is tied to a single domain but can be used in many servers...how would i do that? ... the 2nd server runs nginx and i have already transferred the relevant keys